# Continuity and Differentiability of f(x)

Tags: derivatives, continuity

$$f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    x^2 + 3x + 2       & \quad \text{if } x \leq 0\\
    x^2 - 3x + 2  & \quad \text{if } x > 0\\
  \end{cases}
$$
Prove that f is continuous at $x = 0$ and not differentiable at $x = 0$

My proof:::

$-\delta < x < 0 \Rightarrow |x| < \delta$ 
define $\delta = Min\{1, \frac{\varepsilon}{4}\}$

Then, $|x| < \delta \Rightarrow 4|x| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow |x||x + 3| < \varepsilon$ 
$\Rightarrow |f(x) - 2| < \varepsilon $

$\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x) = f(0)$

$0 < x < \delta \Rightarrow |x| < \delta$ 
define $\delta = Min\{4, \frac{\varepsilon}{3}\}$

Then, $|x| < \delta \Rightarrow 3|x| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow |x||x - 3| < \varepsilon$ 
$\Rightarrow |f(x) - 2| < \varepsilon $

$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = f(0)$ 
Therefore $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} = f'(a)$$ 
$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} \Rightarrow \frac{\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) - f(0)}{\lim_{x \to 0^+} x - 0} \Rightarrow \frac{\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) - \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(0)}{\lim_{x \to 0^+} x}$

and now comes the tricky part I used. Don't know if it's correct.
$\frac{\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^2 - 3x + 2 - \lim_{x \to 0^+} 2}{\lim_{x \to 0^+} x}$

$\frac{(\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \times \lim_{x \to 0^+} x) - 3\lim_{x \to 0^+} x + \lim_{x \to 0^+}2 - \lim_{x \to 0^+} 2}{\lim_{x \to 0^+} x}$

$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x - \lim_{x \to 0^+} 3$
$= -3$

Following the same procedure I can get $\lim_{x \to 0^-} x + \lim_{x \to 0^+} 3$
$= +3$
So the values are different, f is not differentiable at x = 0
Am I using correct methods during this proof?

Comment: Can I just strike through similar limits like I've done here?

Comment: You can't take the limit 'inside' as you have done above - this yields a division by zero.

Comment: If you are allowed to use limit laws it's much simpler in the continuity bit. You can just argue that the limit from the left and right are both $2$ via limit laws. Likewise, the derivatives $f'(x) = 2x-3$ vs. $f'(x) = 2x+3$ have limits $3$ and $-3$ as we approach the origin from left or right. Thus, the double-sided limit to define $f'(0)$ does not exist. But, if you must suffer the epsilonics I guess it's a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second part is not correct, as when "distributing" the limit in both the denominator and numerator you get at $\frac{0}{0}$ undefined form (both limits are $0$.

A simpler argument would be to look at the limit at $0^+$ , $0^-$ and $f(0)$ (observing that $f$, restricted to $[0,\infty)$ (resp. $(-\infty,0]$) is a continuous and even infinitely differentiable function: namely, a polynomial) and conclude they are equal: hence $f$ is continuous at $0$ (and since everywhere else if fine, it is continuous everywhere). But the limit at $0^+$ is easy, it is just evaluating the first polynomial at $0$. (Ditto for the limit at $0^-$).

For differentiability, the same approach works: you know explicitly what $f^\prime$ is on $(0,\infty)$, and what it is on $(-\infty,0)$ (by deriving the two polynomials). To be differentiable at $0$, you need $\lim_{0^+} f^\prime = \lim_{0^-} f^\prime$ (and it is sufficient). But this is not the case, as $\lim_{0^+} f^\prime = \lim_{x\to 0^+} 2x + 3 = 3$, while $\lim_{0^-} f^\prime = \lim_{x\to 0^-} 2x - 3 = -3$.

Comment: Thank you sire for the answer :) Just one question. Can we use $2x + 3$ without proving it?

Comment: If you're allowed to use derivation rules for polynomials, yes.

Comment: Yep we are allowed! So that way I don't have to go through all the hardship proving it right? Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(x) = \begin{cases} g_1(x) , & x \le x_0 \\ g_2(x), & x > x_0\end{cases}$, with $g_1,g_2$ differentiable and $g_1(x_0) = g_2(x_0)$.

It should be clear that $f$ is continuous and differentiable for $x \neq x_0$, we need only consider $x=x_0$.

To show continuity, let $\epsilon>0$. Since $g_1,g_2$ are continuous at $x_0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-x_0| < \delta$, then $|g_k(x)-g_k(x_0)| < \epsilon$. If we consider $x\le x_0$ and $x>x_0$ separately,
and note that $f(x_0)=g_1(x_0)=g_2(x_0)$, we see that $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$, and so $f$ is continuous.

Regarding differentiability, we will show that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ **iff** $g_1'(x_0) = g_2'(x_0)$.

If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, then $
f'(x_0) = \lim_{x\uparrow x_0} {f(x)-f(x_0) \over x - x_0} = g_1'(x_0)$,
and similarly $f'(x_0) = \lim_{x\downarrow x_0} {f(x)-f(x_0) \over x - x_0} = g_2'(x_0)$.

Now suppose $g_1'(x_0) = g_2'(x_0)$. As above, choose $\epsilon>0$ and let $\delta>0$ be such that if $0<|x-x_0| < \delta$, then
$|{g_k(x)-g_k(x_0) \over x - x_0} - g_k'(x_0)| < \epsilon$ for $k=1,2$.
By considering $x\le x_0$ and $x>x_0$ separately, we see that
$|{f(x)-fk(x_0) \over x - x_0} - g_1'(x_0)| < \epsilon$, and so
$f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $f'(x_0) = g_1'(x_0) = g_2'(x_0)$.

In the above, let $g_1(x) = x^2+3x+2, g_2(x) = x^2-3x+2$. Since
$g_1'(0) = 3, g_2'(0) = -3$, we see that $f$ is not differentiable at zero.

Comment: Oops, I did not mean to usurp the other answerer, just to add a broader perspective. If you don't mind, can you change the accepted back to the original please?

Comment: haha okie done :D But this corrects my proof a little bit better :)

Comment: Glad to be able to help :-).